# How to loop over two string lists in single for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

It is pretty simple case I want to join two list string with for loop.
for example

```
player_name =['Messi','Ronaldo']
player_id = ['1','2']
for player_data in player_name,player_id:
    print('player'+player_data+'id'+player_data)
```

But I got

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

Is there a way I can print out `player Messi id 1,player Ronaldo id 2` ?

Comment: Use `zip` https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: Simpy iterate over `index` like `for i in range(len(player_name))`. Then use the `i` to index them

Comment: yes i got answer @IainShelvington

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) funcion

```
player_names =['Messi','Ronaldo']
player_ids = ['1','2']
for player_name, player_id in zip(player_names,player_ids):
    print('player '+player_name+' id '+player_id)
```

there are some better methods to handle stings

Answer (score 1):

```
player_name =['Messi','Ronaldo']
player_id = ['1','2']
for k,name in enumerate(player_name):
    print('player: '+ name +' id:'+player_id[k])
```

Answer (score -1):

Since there are 2 lists in the loop, You should provide 2 variables to unpack the values from the lists.

```
player_name =['Messi','Ronaldo']
player_id = ['1','2']
for name,id in player_name,player_id:
    print('player: '+name+' id: '+id)
```